# script in bash not understood using terminal in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: bash

Can anyone tells me what does this script means found in a `.sh` file:

```
[ ! -n "$T_R" ] && echo "Message Appear" && exit 1;
```

Comment: http://explainshell.com gets you quite a way there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The chained `&&` is a common short-circuit idiom.

Instead of writing

```
if true; then
  if true; then
    echo moo
  fi
fi
```

you can abbreviate to just `true && true && echo moo`.

`echo` will usually succeed so `true && echo moo && exit 1` will execute both the `echo` and the `exit` if `true` succeeds (which obviously it always will).

(There are probably extreme corner cases where `echo` could fail, but if that happens, you are toast anyways so I don't think it makes sense to try to guard against those.)

The `[` is an alias for `test` which is a general comparison helper for shell scripts (in Bash, it's even a built-in).  `test -n` checks whether a string is non-empty.

`!` is the general negation operator, so it inverts the test to checking for an empty string.

(This is slightly unidiomatic, because there is a separate `test -z "$T_R"` which checks specifically for the string being empty.)

Answer (score 2):

Edit: Correcting for misinformation pointed out by tripleee

The brackets `[ ]`
    are an alias for 'test', which tests whether a condition is met. Not to complicate matters, but do note that this is discrete from the the bash shell keyword   `[[ ]]` (Thanks, tripleee for clearing that up!).  See [This post for further details.](https://serverfault.com/questions/52034/what-is-the-difference-between-double-and-single-square-brackets-in-bash) These days, most people seem to use the latter due to its more robust feature set.

Between the brackets, the script is testing to determine whether the variable `"$T_R"` is an empty string.

- The `-n` operator returns true if the length of the string passed to it as an argument is non-empty.
- The `!` inverts the case (the test succeeds if the result is **not
  true**). So in this case, `test` suceeds (returns 0) if the length of
  the string variable `"$T_R"` is **not non-zero ** (i.e. if the
  variable is an empty-string, or is non-existant).

The double-ampersand, `&&` operator means only execute the subsequent code in the event of success, so the message *"Message Appear"* will only be echoed in the event the test succeeds (again, if `"$T_R"` is empty or unset).

Finally, the `&& exit 1` says to exit returning status 1 after successfully echoing the *Message Appear* message.

The `bash` and `test` man pages are extremely helpful  on all of these topics and should be consulted for further details.

Comment: I'm confused.  What do you mean `[[` is an alias for the standalone `test`?  It's the other way around -- `test` and `[` are synonyms and `[[` is a distinct built-in.

Comment: You're right - sorry for the confusion. I've updated my post to correct the mistake. Thanks for setting the record straight!